# Expected std::iter::Iterator, but std::iter::Iterator found

Tags: rust

I am trying to express the following:

Given a matrix and two index increments, return all quadruplets of numbers from the matrix: quadruplets of numbers along the rows, or along the columns, or along some diagonal.

```
use std::iter::Iterator;
use std::iter::Peekable;
use std::ops::Range;

struct Quads<'a> {
   mx: &'a Vec<Vec<u32>>,
   xs: &'a mut Peekable<Range<i32>>,
   ys: &'a mut Peekable<Range<i32>>,
   dx: i32,
   dy: i32,
}

impl<'a> Quads<'a> {
   fn new(mx: &'a Vec<Vec<u32>>, dx: i32, dy: i32) -> Quads<'a> {
      let ys = (if dy < 0 { -3 * dy } else { 0 })..(mx.len() as i32 - if dy > 0 { 4 * dy } else { 0 });
      let xs = 0..0;

      Quads{
         mx: mx,
         xs: &mut xs.peekable(),
         ys: &mut ys.peekable(),
         dx: dx,
         dy: dy,
      }
   }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Quads<'a> {
   type Item = &'a mut dyn Iterator<Item = u32>;

   fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
      while self.xs.peek() == None && self.ys.peek() != None {
         self.xs = &mut ((if self.dx < 0 { -3 * self.dx } else { 0 })..
                         (self.mx[0].len() as i32 - if self.dx > 0 { 4 * self.dx } else { 0 }))
                         .peekable();
         self.ys.next();
      }

      let y = self.ys.peek();
      if y == None {
         return None;
      }

      let y = *y.unwrap();
      let x = self.xs.next().unwrap();

      Some(&mut ((x..).step_by(self.dx as usize)
                      .zip((y..).step_by(self.dy as usize))
                     .take(4)
                     .map(|(x,y)| self.mx[y as usize][x as usize])))
   }
}
```

This produces confusing error messages:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:52:27
   |
52 |                      .map(|(x,y)| self.mx[y as usize][x as usize])))
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 33:4...
  --> src/main.rs:33:4
   |
33 | /    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
34 | |       while self.xs.peek() == None && self.ys.peek() != None {
35 | |          self.xs = &mut ((if self.dx < 0 { -3 * self.dx } else { 0 })..
36 | |                          (self.mx[0].len() as i32 - if self.dx > 0 { 4 * self.dx } else { 0 }))
...  |
52 | |                      .map(|(x,y)| self.mx[y as usize][x as usize])))
53 | |    }
   | |____^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &&mut Quads<'a>
              found &&mut Quads<'a>
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 30:6...
  --> src/main.rs:30:6
   |
30 | impl<'a> Iterator for Quads<'a> {
   |      ^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected std::iter::Iterator
              found std::iter::Iterator
```

It seems to indicate that it has found the same things it was looking for. So what's wrong?

---

**Intended use**

Look at https://projecteuler.net/problem=11

Of course, that problem can be solved in more straightforward ways, but I am learning how to express complex things in Rust. So here I am trying to express a `Quad` that is an `Iterator` that can extract quadruples of numbers from that Euler problem, where each quadruple is an `Iterator` itself.

Everything inside `Quad` represents the state of the `Iterator`. `xs` and `ys` represent the iterators of the coordinates of "the current cell" from which to start the next quadruple. `next` then tries to see if reached the end of the row, and advances to the next row by reinitialising `xs` to a new `Iterator`. When `ys` reached beyond the last row, we've extracted all the quadruples.

Then something like this:

```
for q in Quad::new(mx, 1, 0) {  ... process all quadruples along the rows }
for q in Quad::new(mx, 0, 1) {  ... process all quadruples along the columns }
for q in Quad::new(mx, 1, 1) {  ... process all quadruples along one diagonal }
for q in Quad::new(mx, 1, -1) {  ... process all quadruples along the other diagonal }
```

I think I've got the idea captured, but I don't know what the compiler does not like about it, and consequently how to move forward.

Comment: that very strange rust code, I don't really understand what you try to do.

Comment: @Stargateur I've added the "intended use", if that helps.

Comment: @Stargateur I figured it out. Fancy taking a pass at the statement about memory management for mutable references? (as in: who owns the releasing of the mutably referenced object?)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured it out. It is really not helpful that `rustc` produced such a confusing error message - evidently, it found what it was looking for, but still unsatisfied.

There are several problems with the code as posted. My original assumption has been that by marking a reference as mutable I can tell the compiler that whoever receives the reference is responsible for it henceforth, including memory management. Whereas it may be true in some cases (I am not certain; that's still to figure out), it certainly does not work with `struct` fields (`Quad`'s `xs`) and return values. In this case we can get rid of `&mut` in the declaration of the `xs` and `ys`:

```
struct Quads<'a> {
   mx: &'a Vec<Vec<u32>>,
   xs: Peekable<Range<i32>>,
   ys: Peekable<Range<i32>>,
   dx: i32,
   dy: i32,
}
```

The other problem has been that if it is not a reference, how do you limit the lifetime of a value. (Eg in this case the `Iterator` returned by `next` is valid only for as long as the `mx`)

The other problem has been the expression problem: how do you make `next` return an `Iterator` (I don't want to leak what kind of `Iterator`) so that the compiler is happy. (Eg just `dyn Iterator` won't do - "size is not known at compile time"). These two are solved by using `Box`, which can be annotated with a lifetime, too:

```
impl<'a> Iterator for Quads<'a> {
   type Item = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a>;

   fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
      ...
   }
}
```

The other problem has been that even though the use of `mx` is read-only, the closure `|(x, y)| self.mx[y][x]` captures `self`, which is a mutable reference. That's the easy one: get a local variable, then `move`:

```
  let mx = self.mx;
  Some(Box::new(...
          .map(move |(x, y)| mx[y as usize][x as usize])))
```

Nearly forgot. And the really strange one, which looked fishy even as I typed it originally: `step_by` takes `usize`, which is unsigned, and isn't really constructing a `Range` that enumerates values by adding a given increment; rather it constructs an `Iterator` that skips a given number of elements (pretty much). So, a tuple iterator is needed:

```
struct Tup<T> {
   x: (T, T),
   d: (T, T),
}
...
impl<T: AddAssign + Copy> Iterator for Tup<T> {
   type Item = (T, T);
   fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(T, T)> {
      self.x.0 += self.d.0;
      self.x.1 += self.d.1;
      Some(self.x)
   }
}
```

So instead of zipping two `Iterator`s with `step_by`, you get a `Tup` initialised with known initial values and deltas:

```
  Some(Box::new(Tup::new((x, y), (self.dx, self.dy))
                     .take(4)
                     .map(move |(x, y)| mx[y as usize][x as usize])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be not to export iterators, but pass an operation to run inside.

Comment: Definitely an option. But that also depends on many things. In particular, `Fn` is really an object with everything it needs copied into it. It may also clash with lifetimes and mutability. So you need to predict the intended uses. For example, I had to declare `FnMut` here, because the closure I wanted to pass into it was mutating some state: `fn collatz_seq(mut x: u64, mut f: impl FnMut(u64)->bool)`