# How to hold a Peekable of any iterator in a struct?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a struct:

```
struct Quads<'a> {
    mx: &'a Vec<Vec<u32>>,
    xs: &'a mut Peekable<Range<i32>>,
    ys: &'a mut Peekable<Range<i32>>,
    dx: i32,
    dy: i32,
}
```

I wanted the type of `xs` to be `Peekable<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>`, as that would be a natural thing to want in other languages. Is such an idea expressible in Rust?

That is, "a `Peekable` of some `Iterator` of `i32`", not a `Peekable` of a specific `Iterator`.

Comment: Use boxed trait object: `Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>>`.

Comment: why not https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b85e70bf74dac7042fa92335eb245bf ?

Comment: @edwardw `Iterator.peekable()` returns `Peekable<Self>`. So I really just need to be able to say "any implementation of `Iterator` will do".

Comment: @Stargateur because `T` is not known at call site - it is used by implementation. In this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551596/expected-stditeriterator-but-stditeriterator-found I can specify it is always a `Range`, but I am learning how things natural in other languages get expressed in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `Peekable<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>` is that `dyn Trait` represents a type dynamically (obviously) which means that it is a [dynamically sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts). Those cannot be expressed directly as a struct field (except through obscure means).

So @edwardw's comment is the way to go. Putting the iterator in a `Box` ensures the field has a fixed size but the iterator itself can be whatever size it wants. `Box` also naturally [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Iterator-for-Box%3CI%2C%20A%3E) `Iterator` if the contents implement `Iterator`. Here's the changes (also following your lead in [your other Q&A](/a/59576677/2189130) that they should be stored directly and not as `&mut` references):

```
struct Quads<'a> {
    mx: &'a Vec<Vec<u32>>,
    xs: Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>>,
    ys: Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>>,
    dx: i32,
    dy: i32,
}
```

Which you can then create via `Box::new(0..dx) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32>>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a0cad29e79a8fc8a4749440b93a1818)).

If the expected concrete type is `Range<i32>` then this probably isn't a problem, but if you did want to store more exotic iterators that require lifetimes, then you may need to add a `+ 'a` constraint as shown in this answer: [How can I make `Box<dyn Iterator>` peekable and avoid lifetime errors?](/a/59576677/2189130)