# How can I make `Box<dyn Iterator>` peekable and avoid lifetime errors?

Tags: rust

I have the following type definition:

```rust
pub struct UTF8Chars {
    bytes: Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>>,
}
```

Now I'm wondering how to actually create an instance of this struct.

I've tried *(and yes, this is inside a trait implementation if that is an important detail)*:

```rust
impl<'a> ToUTF8Chars for &'a str {
    fn utf8_chars(self) -> UTF8Chars {
        let bytes = Box::new(self.bytes()).peekable();

        UTF8Chars { bytes }
    }
}
```

That gives me the error:

```
expected struct `Peekable<Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = u8> + 'static)>>`
   found struct `Peekable<Box<std::str::Bytes<'_>>>`
```

*[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d69eee7953a6392d12c81a77a21cf15a)*

Forgive me if I try weird things, but I haven't gotten the hang of this intricate trait stuff yet. For all I know, rust-analyzer was telling me that `Bytes` in fact an `impl Iterator<Item = u8>`. So, next thing I tried was casting it first:

```rust
let bytes = Box::new(self.bytes()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>;

UTF8Chars { bytes: bytes.peekable() }
```

That sort of works, but now the borrow checker is complaining:

```
impl<'a> ToUTF8Chars for &'a str {
     -- lifetime `'a` defined here
     fn utf8_chars(self) -> UTF8Chars {
         let bytes = Box::new(self.bytes()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

I'm not exactly sure what is going out of scope here... as far as I know, I own the result from `.bytes()` (I also tried with an additional `.clone()` in case that assumption was incorrect), I own the `Box`, the `Box` is passed to `Peekable`, and finally `Peekable` is passed to `UTF8Chars`. What *exactly* is the issue here? Why do I somehow need to outlive `static`...?

I found this issue that seems similar, sadly no answer: [Peekable of an Iterator in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551656/peekable-of-an-iterator-in-struct).

#### Why I want to do this?

Well, mainly because I don't really care, or am unable to care what exactly the underlying data is. I just need to know that I can `.peek()`, and `.next()`, etc. This is, because sometimes I want to assign different things to `self.bytes`. For example, `Chain<...>`, or `Copied<...>` instead of a simple `vec::IntoIter<...>`.

If there is an alternative approach to this, I'm happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, next thing I tried was casting it first:
>
> ```rust
> let bytes = Box::new(self.bytes()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>;
> ```

This is the right thing to do in this situation, though I would write it with a type annotation on the `let`, instead of `as`.

```rust
let bytes: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> = Box::new(self.bytes());
```

In particular, there must be a point at which the *unsizing coercion* from `Box<Bytes>` to `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>` happens, and that point must be before the `Box` is contained in something else (because it actually produces a different `Box`, one with a vtable pointer added).

In some cases, just `as _` (unspecified type) is sufficient to prompt the compiler into not immediately concluding that the type is the same as the incoming type.

> I'm not exactly sure what is going out of scope here...

Every trait object (`dyn`) type has a lifetime, often implicit. This lifetime specifies how long instances of that type are guaranteed valid — or, from the opposite perspective, what references the trait object is allowed to borrow/contain.

When you don't specify that lifetime, and the trait object is in a `Box`, [lifetime elision rules make that lifetime be `'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes). That's why you have an error: you're trying to put a `Bytes<'a>` in a place where `'static` is required.

In order to allow your boxed iterator to borrow, you must define the types and traits to have a lifetime.

```rust
use core::iter::Peekable;

pub struct UTF8Chars<'a> {
    bytes: Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a>>,
}

trait ToUTF8Chars<'a> {
    fn utf8_chars(self) -> UTF8Chars<'a>;
}

impl<'a> ToUTF8Chars<'a> for &'a str {
    fn utf8_chars(self) -> UTF8Chars<'a> {
        let bytes: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a> = Box::new(self.bytes());

        UTF8Chars {
            bytes: bytes.peekable(),
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add a lifetime, then you must only use owning iterators (e.g. `String::into_bytes(s).into_iter()`). With the lifetime, you can use both owning and borrowing iterators.

Comment: Ah, the trait also has a lifetime, of course! I did know about the `+ lifetime` thing, but didn't know it was required here. Does one just have to know this, or is there some way I could have gained that information from the error message?

Comment: @Elias Not a lot of good clues, but "cast requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`" implies that there is a `'static` bound _somewhere_ in the type you're casting to. The compiler doesn't just make up `'static` bounds from nothing, so a good question to ask at that point is where that bound is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `dyn Trait` types are actually `dyn Trait + 'static` by default, which means they're not allowed to borrow any data. That's a problem for you because the iterator returned by calling `bytes()` on a `&'a str` borrows from that `str` and thus cannot outlive `'a`. But `'a` doesn't outlive `'static` so you can't make a `dyn Iterator + 'static` from it.

As you might have guessed, the solution here is adding some more general lifetime bounds, first to the struct:

```
pub struct UTF8Chars<'a> {
    //              ^^^^ now generic over 'a
    bytes: Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a>>,
    //                  ------------------------^^^^
    // the iterator is now allowed to borrow data for 'a
}
```

Then to the trait:

```
trait ToUTF8Chars {
    fn utf8_chars<'a>(self) -> UTF8Chars<'a> where Self: 'a;
    //           ^^^^ also generic over 'a         ^^^^^^^^ self can borrow data for 'a
}
```

Depending on your exact use case, using a borrowed receiver might be nicer, though:

```
trait ToUTF8Chars {
    fn utf8_chars<'a>(&'a self) -> UTF8Chars<'a>;
    //                ^^^^ just borrow `self` for 'a
}
```

I'm sure there's a cases where these two aren't the same (object safety, probably?) but I can't pin point a specific situation off the top of my head.

And finally the implementation:

```
impl<'b> ToUTF8Chars for &'b str {
    fn utf8_chars<'a>(self) -> UTF8Chars<'a> where Self: 'a {
        let bytes = Box::new(self.bytes()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>;

        UTF8Chars { bytes: bytes.peekable() }
    }
}
```

or

```
impl ToUTF8Chars for str {
    fn utf8_chars<'a>(&'a str) -> UTF8Chars<'a> {
        let bytes = Box::new(self.bytes()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>;

        UTF8Chars { bytes: bytes.peekable() }
    }
}
```

for the alternative version of `ToUTF8Chars`.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, sadly someone else was a bit faster, so I'll probably accept theirs. This answer still contains viable information, though. I think I would prefer this trait declaration: `fn utf8_chars<'a>(self) -> UTF8Chars<'a> where Self: 'a;`, as that would allow me to do both `impl ... for str`, and `impl ... for &str`, no? But I'm not an expert by any means. *(you might also be able to answer a comment I've written under the other answer)*

Comment: True about implementing for `str` and `&str` but you can't get call functions on a `str` without borrowing it so that doesn't buy you much. As for your other question, I think you may just have to be aware of the default `'static` bound. Trait objects have historically never been the most well documented part of Rust and I couldn't quickly find that info in The Book or the nomicon, although I'm sure it's there somewhere.

Comment: @Elias I ended up finding it in the reference under lifetime elision rules (which makes sense when you think about it): https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes